# Interactive login is required. Use 'azure login' to interactively login

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-cli

Trying to [run Kubernetes on Azure](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/), I'm stuck on `./azure-login.js -u <your_username>`.

I'm getting the following:

```
[aii@localhost azure]$ ./azure-login.js -u aii@aii_domain.com
info:    Executing command login
Password: ********
+ Authenticating...                                                            
error:   Interactive login is required. Use 'azure login' to interactively login.
info:    Error information has been recorded to /home/aii/.azure/azure.err
error:   login command failed
```

More info:

```
[aii@localhost azure]$ azure --version
0.10.0 (node: 4.3.1)
```

BTW, my account is BizSpark Plus if it matter..

Answer (score 1):

Add the following commands first:

```
azure account download
```

it will [guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-connect/#use-a-publish-settings-file) you to download `.publishsettings` file from browser which you should use for:

```
azure account import <downloaded file>

azure account set <"name of your subscription">
```

Azure login  only works from a work or school id, which really means an AAD object (identity). If you have a Microsoft account, you can only "connect" with the  azure account import  command that takes a .publishsettings file that you have to download. (it's a cert file)

This is actually a feature of Azure, although I think we don't communicate well here. Turns out that everyone has a default Azure Active Directory domain that they get for free.

At a larger level, Azure has two management APIs: 
 1. Service management, which can be used with either work ids or Microsoft account ids, and 
 2. Resource management, which is the new stuff and can be used only with work or school ids, and that works only with the  azure login  functionality.

Comment: Thanks! where can I see my subscription name?

Comment: In the left-hand menu at portal.azure.com, furthest down there is a tab called Subscriptions. It lists your subscription ID's and the corresponding names (they are just called Subscription, yours will likely be named something like Bizspark Plus).

Comment: the first command yield "error: missing required argument 'file'"

Comment: I've made these steps above but it's still doesn't work :-(

Comment: Sorry, my bad. First you have to run
azure account download

to download your .publishsettings file, which you then use as argument to azure account import. More information here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-command-line-tools/

Comment: I did it, and also edit your answer (you need to except it) but still get my first error..